# Xcode crash on swift files

Tags: xcode, swift

I have internal error while compiling my project on Xcode on roughly half of my Swift files, as you may see in the attached screenshot
[image: Xcode error report]
Each of which terminating with a line in the files usually of the form:

```
static let mapController=viewControllersFactorySingleton.sharedFactory().mapController
```

in one case I tried to replace the code with:

```
static var mapController:MovableAnnotationDelegate!
override public class func initialize(){
   mapController=viewControllersFactorySingleton.sharedFactory().mapController
}
```

But I had the crash in the initialization:

> 1. While emitting IR SIL function @_TZFC10inArrivoHD14PalettaTraffic10initializefMS0_FT_T_ for
>      'initialize' at /Users/fbartolom/Documents/cocoa
>      applications/inArrivoHD/inArrivoHD/PalettaTraffic.swift:25:21

previously it was in the single line.

What is wrong in the code to the point of even crashing Xcode?

Comment: I've seen curious crashes like this when compiling a project created with an earlier version of Xcode. If this is the case in your situation, I'd suggest selecting the target (the top of the tree in the project navigator panel on the left) and then choosing "Validate settings..." on the "Editor" menu.

Comment: As said, once I moved the factory class to Swift, the crash temporarily went away. At present my problem i exporting a variable of type protocol from Swift to objective-c, consequence of the solution hereafter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash went away by also porting the factory class to Swift. The crash must be due to the interoperation between the swift and objective-c modules; what is getting increasingly shaky.

Answer (score 1):

A crash in the compiler is always a bug in the compiler. Open a radar (bugreport.apple.com).

You can try to narrow down exactly what is causing the crash by commenting out different parts of your code until it stops crashing. And then you can try to do something else. Most of the time it means your code is incorrect, and rather than generate an error, the compiler crashes. Sometimes if you look at all the log output (click the lines the right of the filename), you can figure out where it might be, but sometimes you can't and you'll have to use trial and error to narrow it down.

Of course make sure you've checked with the very latest beta version of Xcode. It's possible they've fixed the bug, and that that version will give you a proper error that you can use to fix your code in older versions of Xcode.

Comment: I also tried with Xcode 7.2 but the errors stayed. As you may see I started narrowing the thing down, never imagining problems in the code instead of being reported as such crash the compiler!

Comment: Is `viewControllersFactorySingleton` a global variable or a class? (Classes should always be leading-caps, so I assume a global variable.) You can't rely on a global variable in a `static` definition (or in `initialize`). This code doesn't make a lot of sense anyway; why is this static? (It has a strong feeling of very broken architecture, too. Feels very Java-like with a "view controller factory" which is almost never how you do things in Cocoa.)